# Random vector with a fixed sum: Distribution for its components

Tags: r, distributions

Suppose that I have a random vector $X=(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n)$ where each $0\leq p_i\leq 1$ and $\sum p_i = 1$. I would like to find distribution for each component $p_i$ and also other general expressions such as $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4$.

I have used function [RandVec](https://rdrr.io/cran/Surrogate/man/RandVec.html) in R to generated one million vectors. Histograms for each $p_i$ can be seen here (for case $n=8$).

EDIT: Thank to @wuber, I have realized if I do not add any constraints, except sum = 1, then they follow Dirichlet(1, 1, ..., 1). Please correct me if this is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: A nice family of such distributions is the [Dirichlet](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dirichlet+distribution). You can also take (literally) *any* positive random variable $(q_1,\ldots, q_n)$ and normalize its values by their sum.  But could you explain what you mean by "find" a distribution?  Based on what criteria or information?

Comment: Thanks @wuber, I have realized if I do not add any constraints, except sum = 1, then they follow Dirichlet(1, 1, ..., 1).

Comment: @wuber: It seems that permutation of the component does not have the same distribution, even with Dir(1, ..., 1). Do you think so, although intuitively, I think it should be.

Comment: Dirichlet$(\alpha,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha)$ distributions are all exchangeable.  BTW, nothing I wrote implies the solution requires $\alpha=1.$

Comment: I have a typo that makes a wrong statement.